# Interface with self-referencing property

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a TypeScript interface that I want to reference itself.  This is tedious to construct manually, so I wrote a helper function.

```
function insertSelf<T, K extends keyof T>(prop: K, o: Omit<T, K>): T {
    return (o as any)[prop] = o as T // close-enough
}
```

Then given an instance, I can construct and self-assign it in one statement.

```
interface Foo {
    a: number,
    b: number,
    c: this
}

const f: Foo = insertSelf<Foo, 'c'>('c', {a: 1, b: 2})
// f.c points back to f
```

The unfortunate thing is having to repeat the parameter name as both a [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html) and a string literal value.  The question is if there's any generic construction that would avoid that.  I'm guessing the answer is "no", at least without sacrificing compiler checking of the property name or other record fields.

The best option I've found is to simplify the call with a bind beforehand.

```
const insertFoo = insertSelf<Foo, 'c'>.bind(null, 'c')
const f: Foo = insertFoo({a: 1, b: 2})
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mZB0Dm) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I don't think so.  Adding the self-referring property instead of omitting it is some clever juggling, but I already have an interface with a property, and the goal is for the input to be able to omit the property and for the output to have it and for that to be parameterized so it works for any similar interface and property name.

Comment: https://tsplay.dev/wR1yxW I would do it with a class

Comment: Can you demonstrate why that's a problem?  You could easily write `const f: Foo = ...` with my implementation as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mALA4N).   If that doesn't suffice, then could you please [edit] the question to show how you'd like to call `insertSelf()`, preferably something that would fail with my suggestion? Because right now I'm not seeing the difference between what you want and what I've given you.

Comment: My apologies @jcalz, I was getting an error with it previously and now I'm not sure why.  That does seem to do the job, and it's a definite improvement over what I thought I'd have to settle for.

Comment: So then I can write up an answer? I'm not missing anything?

Comment: Absolutely, I appreciate it, and this definitely expanded my sense of what TS generics can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version doesn't really work well with TypeScript's inference algorithm for [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), and forces you to manually specify the generic type arguments, leading to duplication. Ideally you want the type checker to infer your types, but inferring `T` from a value of type `Omit<T, K>` is mostly not going to work ([the `Omit` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) is implemented in terms of a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), and TypeScript can't really do much analysis on generic conditional types).

---

Instead, you should consider making the inference as simple as possible, by asking the compiler to infer `T` from a value of type `T`.  It would look like this:

```
function insertSelf<T, K extends PropertyKey>(prop: K, o: T): ⋯
```

And then all that remains is to describe the return type in terms of `T` and `K`.  Here's one approach:

```
type Self<K extends PropertyKey, T> =
    T & { [P in K]: Self<K, T> }
```

So a `Self<K, T>` is a value of type `T` which also has a property of type `Self<K, T>` at the property with key `K`.  This is a recursive type, describing a relationship much like the [polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) you were using in `Foo`.

The implementation could be

```
function insertSelf<T, K extends PropertyKey>(prop: K, o: T): Self<K, T>;
function insertSelf(prop: PropertyKey, o: any) {
    return o[prop] = o;
}
```

where I'm just using a single-call-signature [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) to suppress any errors that come from the compiler not understanding how `return o[prop]=o` works or relates to `Self<K, T>`.

---

Let's try it out:

```
const f = insertSelf('c', { a: 1, b: 2 });
// const f: Self<"c", { a: number;  b: number; }>
console.log(f.a.toFixed(2)) // 1.00
console.log(f.c.c.c.b.toFixed(2)) // 2.00
```

Looks good, the type of `f` is `Self<"c", {a: number, b: number}>` and thus it has all the properties you expect.

Also note that this doesn't preclude you from using your custom interface with the `this` property type in it:

```
interface Foo {
    a: number,
    b: number,
    c: this
}
const foo: Foo = f; // okay
```

That assignment succeeds because the compiler is able to verify that `Self<"c", { a: number;  b: number; }>` is assignable to `Foo`.  So if you are unsatisfied with seeing the `Self` type, you have options.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0#code/FAFwngDgpgBAylANgMwDwGkZQB4igOwBMBnGABQCcB7aC8dKMAGhgBUA+GAXmBj7ZgAyGAG8YAbTIwAlvhjoAugC54SNOhYcYAX2DBkAV3wBjENKpzZxKHQQpUrFphx4ipSjRv1G7ABQRqCBUNGCoVVgBKFTt1TXYAbn0jU3NLfGtbNX9AlQ9ab2ZQlQBDfDAI0V5+CigQAwo5KnEAmgVuUMTdYGMLYhAYZHarLxjfAHJjMZYxYpUARhYAIxUAJh0IxIB6TZge9P7kaLVUACJjE+mYWZh8AwBbRZt4vmWb+8eKZ+12bt6qRCgADpEFQAOa+ZCA4qAkBUABi0mwUEIvhWEQq2xgc0BAAYcb90v8gSDwZDjIDyeTFjD4Yjkaj0TBMStcfjgLI8BRkMVjLA4VQqJV+FcVLcHjYmFUXqL3hKpbsVCAABbSYjAXR7PoDAUqfmCrgDZ6YqgAa2KYCAA)